# Does link aggregation uses the full bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, port-channel

If I setup a 2x 1Gig ports with link aggregation, will I get 2Gigs bandwidth or less? how less?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends. If it is done correctly, each flow would get a maximum of 1 Gbps, but with multiple flows, you will be able to use the full 2 Gbps.

Some people, on some equipment, can, and will, configure round-robin balancing, but that leads to problems like out-of-order packet delivery, which can completely kill real-time applications, and it can actually degrade your performance to less than 1 Gbps per flow..

Correctly done, you use a hash algorithm to determine which flow gets which member interface. This will limit a single flow to a percentage (possibly 100% on a lightly used link) of a single link in the channel. This will average out to using the whole 2 Gbps of the channel with multiple flows.

Comment: You should note that a small number of flows is likely not to distributed evenly across the LAG. Sometimes, tweaking the IP addresses, port numbers (for precisely defined workloads) and such can help, depending on the hardware on its traffic distribution scheme/configuration.